# Reporting on Chatter

Tags: reporting, chatter

I need to be able to report on files posted to Chatter. It doesn't look like you can through Chatter activity reports.

Is there a best way to go about this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can get information on files posted to Chatter on a file by file basis.  Go to the file's detail page and click the "show file report" link.  You'll get a "File and Content Engagement Report" for that file.

If you customize the report and remove the file ID, you can get a report that works across multiple files.

There's more details on this [here](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_summer14_release_notes.pdf) in the Summer 14 release notes (starting on page 86).